# Merging excelsheets (12 excel sheets with each excel sheet has more than 140k rows) into 1 data frame then exporting it to CSV /txt

Tags: r, excel

I am a newbie and need help with manipulating the data I have.

I have an excel workbook with 12 excel sheet with each sheet having approximately 140k rows.

Is it possible to turn them all into 1 via R and then export the file to csv or txt please?

Thank you

Tried using reasxl and tidy verse

```
Path<- "C:/data"
Setwd(path)
Sheet=excel_sheets("df.xlsx")
Data= lapply(setNames(sheet, sheet), function(x) read_excel("df.xlsx", sheet=x))
Data=bind_rows(Data, id="sheet")
Lapply(Data, function(x) write.table(Data(x), 'data0.csv', append =T, sep= ','))
```

And I still don't get a one file having all the data sheets combined.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple approach using `data.table` and `openxlsx`. I'm not sure about the full structure of your data but you can easily perform other operations when reading in the data (if needed) before combining it all and writing to an output file.

```
library(data.table)
library(openxlsx)

file <- 'my_file.xlsx' #full path and name of your file
sheet_names <- getSheetNames(file = file)

# loop through sheetnames to read data
data_list <- lapply(sheet_names, function(z){
  dat <- as.data.table(read.xlsx(xlsxFile = file, sheet = z))
  dat$sheet <- z #added to check which sheet the data was retrieved from
  
  # other operations could be added here, e.g. any sheets that contain
  # "raw" in the name need addl. calculations 
  return(dat)
})

# bind all data together
data_combined <- rbindlist(l = data_list, use.names = T, fill = T)

# write to a csv file - xlsx might exceed max. allowable rows
fwrite(x = data_combined, file = 'new_file_name.csv')
```